# Angular calendar click event

Tags: angular, angular-calendar

I'm based on [that thread](https://angular-calendar.com/#/kitchen-sink).

I could add a method allowing to show a modal (popup) after clicking on an existing event as presented by that capture:

[image]

with that code:

```
 <mwl-calendar-week-view
    *ngSwitchCase="CalendarView.Week"
    [viewDate]="viewDate"
    [events]="events"
    [refresh]="refresh"
    (eventTimesChanged)="eventTimesChanged($event)"
    (eventClicked)="openModal($event.event)">
```

I'm stucked on how displaying a modal after clicking on an empty cell which doesn't have any event like explained by that capture:

[image]

Could you please give me some suggestions. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve my problem, I refer to that thread https://angular-calendar.com/#/drag-to-create-events.

In fact, once I clicked to an empty cell, a new event is created.
And that what I'm asking for.

I got that workaround from @SariaEssid reply.

Answer (score 0):

What html element has the empty cell?

You can do (click) on any html element, e.g.

```
<div (click)="onClickEmptyCell()"><!-- empty cell --></div>
```

Comment: Hello Sir @ThorstenRintelen, thanks a lot for your reply. I'd like to do modification on `<mwl-calendar-week-view` (I added the code to my question) --> the `(eventClicked)` is only works with cell with exiting event (like presented with picture 1). That cannot be done with empty cell (cell with no event : like presented with picture 2). Have you please any idea to do that ?. Thanks again Sir.